Construct this flow from local and remote sources
I'm struggling to create a flow that satisfies the conditions commonly found in offline supported apps.
1.if local results exist, emit those first.
2.then emit remote results.
3.persist remote results into Room.
4.an exception should be emitted if there were 0 emissions.  So in practice suppose

If local query returns no results, either because it's an initial
call or due to an error, try the network.
If the network fails,
throw an exception.  Otherwise emit the network results.
If local query returns results, emit.
fetch from the network and either emit
results or fail silently.

A failure should be thrown iff both local and remote sources lack results.
Something like
var localResults = emptyList<Movie>()
flow {
    localResults = localSrc.getMovies()
    if (localResults.isNotEmpty()) emit(localResults)
    try {
        val remoteResults = remoteSrc.getMovies()
        localSrc.insert(remoteResults)
        emit(remoteResults)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
      if (localResults.isEmpty()) throw IllegalStateException()
    }
}
  

If localSrc.getMovies() fails it throws an exception but I want to resume fetching from remote because it may be produce some results.
Edit: Solution
suspend fun getMoviesFlow(id: String): Flow<List<Movie>> {
        var fromLocal = emptyList<Movie>()
        return flow {
            try {
                fromLocal = localDataSource.getMovies().map { it.toDomain() }
                if (fromLocal.isNotEmpty()) emit(fromLocal)
            } catch (localEx: Exception) {
                // so you can resume to a network emission
            }
            try {
                val fromNetwork = fromNetwork(id)
                emit(fromNetwork)
            } catch (remoteEx: Exception) {
                if (fromLocal.isEmpty()) throw IllegalStateException(
                    "fail to fetch movies"
                )
            }
        }
    }

To broot.  "fromLocal" is a local variable so it wouldnt be shared amongst multiple invocations to getMoviesFlow(id), but I could put it in the flow and my results would be the same.

Why not simply put localSrc.getMovies() in another try and ignore the error?

Also, I'm not sure it is a good idea to define localResults outside of the flow {} block. The same flow could be collected multiple times concurrently and then they'll share and mutate the same variable.

fromLocal is not shared between multiple invocations of getMoviesFlow, but it is shared between multiple collections of the same flow. Please note by answering me in the question description, I don't know you did this - I found your comment purely by accident ;-)

So if I call '''getMoviesFlow''' once, and collect it twice fromLocal would be overwritten?

fromLocal will be shared by both collections, this is correct. Maybe it is not a problem in this specific case, but generally, we should be aware of this.
